How to perform CPU stress testing with Prime95 in the command-line mode？
I want to use Prime95 to perform a CPU stress test on the server, which does not have a graphical interface. I encountered two problems while using it.
Problem 1: I start the test using the command ./mprime -m. During the first launch, there are various configurable options available for me to configure (including the scale of the test). However, when I use Ctrl+C to stop a test and then try to launch it again using ./mprime -m, there are no configurable options available anymore, and instead, it directly enters a main menu. How could I properly stop/restart mprime tests.
$ sudo ./mprime -m
[Main thread Aug  5 10:50] Mersenne number primality test program version 30.19 build 20
[Main thread Aug  5 10:50] Optimizing for CPU architecture: AMD Zen, L2 cache size: 192x1 MB, L3 cache size: 24x32 MB
         Main Menu

     1.  Test/Primenet
     2.  Test/Workers
     3.  Test/Status
     4.  Test/Continue
     5.  Test/Exit
     ...

Problem 2: I want to control mprime not to use AVX-512 instructions. According to the documentation, I should set options in the local.txt file, but I cannot find the local.txt file.

You need to Create the file. That documentation mentioned nothing about AVX512 or local.txt (only 2 instances nether are relevant)
